# Loading CA certificate from memory

Tags: c++, boost, openssl, boost-asio

I am trying to load CA certificate from memory instead of file. But I keep getting handshake error while connecting. The file loading works perfectly, memory loading fails. What am I missing?

```
std::ifstream file("message_server_ca.crt");
std::vector<char> fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
boost::asio::const_buffer buffer(&fileContents.at(0),fileContents.size());

bool useFile = false;  // switch between file and memory loading.
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_peer);

if(useFile)
{
    // This works perfectly!
    ctx.load_verify_file("message_server_ca.crt");
}
else
{
    // This fails the handshake (asio.ssl:336134278)
    ctx.use_certificate(buffer,boost::asio::ssl::context_base::pem);
}

client c(io_service, ctx, iterator);
io_service.run();
```

Comment: You are using two different functions. `load_verify_file` vs. `use_certificate`. It should be `use_certificate` vs. `use_certificate_file`.

Comment: use_certificate_file doesn't work either. So I used load_verify_file which works.

Comment: I saw in other threads about use_private_key_file method. But this is a SSL client and I don't specify private key while using load_verify_file method.

Comment: use the error code version of [`use_certificate`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/use_certificate/overload2.html) and find the error description.

Comment: I have tried that too, it doesn't give any error there. The error happen during handshake, when I call socket_.lowest_layer().async_connect() function.

Comment: Just edited the problem to mention I am talking about CA certificate.

Comment: This can be done with pure openssl api but I never used the boost wrapper. If you are using `SSL_CTX_use_certificate()` with a **self signed** ca cert then you probably get a `X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY` error. When I use a self signed cert (or certs) in my ca bundle then I create my `X509` objects (can do that from memory) and I use one of the following function call combinations: 1.) `X509_STORE_new()` `X509_STORE_add_cert()` `SSL_CTX_set_cert_store()` 2.) `SSL_CTX_get_cert_store()` `X509_STORE_add_cert()`. Try searching for these in the source of the boost implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you want [`add_certificate_authority()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/add_certificate_authority.html):

> This function is used to add one trusted certification authority from
>   a memory buffer.

`use_certificate()` and `use_certificate_file()` are for the server or client certificate presented in the handshake, i.e. *not* the CA used to test those certificates.

These functions (`load_verify_file()` and `add_certificate_authority()`) are not consistently named. I guess it is because the memory buffer versions were added relatively recently.